# Is it possible to transfer ether from different wallets using php

Tags: ether

I am developing a payment interface where each user will get different wallet address to send ether. After successful transaction I want to move those to another wallet. There is no connection with any contract. Both the acount's private keys and public keys are available.

I tried [this one](https://github.com/sc0Vu/web3.php). But it doesn't support transaction. Searched for many solutions and I couldn't get a solution yet.

I believe that anyone can direct me to the solution.

Thanks in advance for your valuable time and help.